# Spring + Hibernate: No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement the following: clear some details from DB on SpringSecurity logout handler. The main problem that after trying to get user details from DB I get this error. The rest of code and even the same method work fine in other cases.

```
public class CurrentUserLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private RequestsService requestsService;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private OffersService offersService;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (authentication != null) {
            UserDetailsExtended details = (UserDetailsExtended) authentication.getPrincipal();
            User user = usersService.get(details.getId()); // fails here

            requestsService.unlockAllByBackoffice(user);
            offersService.unlockAllByBackoffice(user);
        }

        setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

Config:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ejl.butler.object.data" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">${hibernate.cache.region.factory_class}</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

DAO:

```
public User get(final Long id) {
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, false);

        return (User) session.get(User.class, id);
    }
```

Spring security config:

```
<logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>
```

Exception:

```
No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:356)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:202)
```

`@Transactional` resolves the problem but I can't understand why? I mean it fails only in this handler in all other calls this method works fine without this annotation!

Thank you in advance!

UPD:
My temporary solution is to add `@Transactional` to whole `onLogoutSuccess` method.. It works)

Comment: Is your logout url intercepted by Spring MVC?

Comment: @shamimz I added security config to question.. No, I just specified the logout handler but the url itself isn't intercepted by Spring

Comment: Can you submit what error message you are getting?

Comment: @shamimz By the way.. I think if I specified logout url in config so it should be intercepted by Spring automatically

Comment: Do you by any chance use a `OpenSessionInViewFilter` or interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined a `TransactionManager` in your spring context you have to specify `@Transactional` somewhere in the stack. Otherwise you will get the exception you encountered because you are trying to run a query outside of a transaction.

There are workarounds to this such specifying `current_session_context_class` in your hibernate configuration to `thread` or

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
```

<del>but it's not production safe.</del>.

The possible values for `current_session_context_class` are `jta`, `thread` and `managed`. Further to that, `jta` and `thread` are supported by hibernate out of box. `thread` context is used in most stand alone hibernate apps or those based on light weight frameworks like Spring and `jta` is used in Java EE environments.

Also try `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` instead of `SessionFactoryUtils.getSession()`.

Comment: both of them aren't production safe?

Comment: I just trying to understand why the same piece of code works fine in other cases

Comment: Could you give more details on what other cases this code works okay? Also, where do you apply the @Transactional annotation in your code?

Comment: Thats the point that I do not need the `@Transactional` annotation until now.. And the same method `usersDao.get(id)` worked fine!

Comment: My point is that I receive this exception only in LogoutSuccessHandler's `onLogoutSuccess` method...

Comment: Try sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() instead of SessionFactoryUtils.getSession()

Comment: Ok, the problem reproduces only inside any of spring security methods.. is there any way to pass an transaction manager to it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'only inside any of spring security methods'?

Comment: Try `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`

Comment: When using spring NEVER mess around with the `current_session_context_class` property of hibernate. Unless you use JTA. Anuthing else (or setting it to thread) will break proper Spring transaction management (Spring has its own `CurrentSessionContext` implementation for proper integration)!. Next to that you really should use `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession` insteaf of the utility class you have now.